# Why FBSDKGraphRequest can not use out of main thread?

Tags: ios, multithreading, facebook-graph-api

When I put Facebook Graph API call to a working queue, it does not return. Any idea why? It would be easier writing code without put it on main thread. I would not nest calls if I need "me/friends" and "me" too.

```
let gr = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "/me/friends", parameters: nil)
        gr.startWithCompletionHandler({connection, _result, error in
```

Comment: If you have more informations about this I am really interested on the answer.

Comment: I think it is a small glitch, it will not block the GUI, how do you see?

Comment: In my case I perform many request in a for loop to get `pages` first and then n `post` from those pages. The GUI is blocked for a short time. I haven't found any solution yet!

Comment: Just to confirm for everyone — I have made a barebones test project which just authorises a user and then sends an `FBSDKGraphRequest` and this request never completes if it is started on a background thread but has no problem on the main thread. At some stage I will try to report this as a bug.